Stretched texture
I have been recently tried to make ice  cream in Blender 4.1, and with the ice cream cone, the texture is stretched irregularly (idk if you can say it but it's stretched at random places). Can anybody help pls ?

Edit: For thoses who asked it, here's what the UV looks like. Thanks for responding fast!

I imagine you already checked the UV map to be not stretched...

...and if not would you mind at least showing a screenshot of the UV map to let us check if it seems to be stretched?

... Probably some subdividion issue if UV Is correct? BTW UV Rotation 45 Is correct?

If you are still looking for the answer please share simplified blend file just with a cone via blend-exchange.com
